# How to get selected row field from gridview in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I am developing a aspx page with Gridview control.    here i am pasting my code

```
                    <Columns>

                     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Request">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="sendrequest" runat="server" Text="SendRequest" CommandName="SendRequest"></asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="FirstName">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="fname" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("fname") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="LastName">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lname" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("lname") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="EMailID">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="email" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("email") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Image">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Image ID="img" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("imagepath") %>' Width="100" Height="100" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Request">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="viewprofile" runat="server" Text="ViewFullProfile" CommandName="ViewProfile"
                    a href ='<%#"ViewProfile.aspx?email="+DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"email") %>'>
                    </asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>


                    </Columns>



                </asp:GridView>
```

My question is  i need email value of which LinkButton(SendRequest) clicked that row email value

please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handle the GridView RowCommand event:

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e) 
{ 
    if (e.CommandName.Equals("SendRequest")) 
    { 
       string strEmail = GridView1.DataKeys[Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)].Value.ToString();
       lbltest.Text = strEmail; 
    } 
}
```

that is assuming you have the DataKeyNames set as *email*.
You must also set the CommandArgument of the *sendRequest* button to

```
CommandArgument="<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>
```

Comment: I tried above code but getting error                                      Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index

Comment: protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName.Equals("SendRequest"))
        {
            string strEmail = GridView1.DataKeys[Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)].Value.ToString();
            lbltest.Text = strEmail;

        }
    }